# Proving that equality is applicable to any N number

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

$a_{n}$ is a sequence of numbers defined by:

$a_{0}$ = −1

$a_{1}$  = 3

$a_{n+2}$  = 6$a_{n}$  − $a_{n+1}$ + 4n + 1

I have to prove that for every natural number n this equality is applicable:

$a_{n}$  = $2^{n}$ − $(-3)^{n}$ − n − 1

Any ideas/hints how to proceed? I have no idea what to do with that.

Sorry for bad English. That is not my first language.

Comment: If $b_n=2^n-(-3)^n-n-1$ then it would suffice to show that $b_0=a_0, b_1=a_1$ and that $b_n$ also satisfies the recursion $b_{n+2}=6b_n-b_{n+1}+4n+1$ (since that recursion defines a sequence uniquely up to initial conditions).

Comment: The comment from @lulu is correct, but it might be useful to mention that the parenthetical point at the end of that comment would be proved by strong induction on $n$. Alternatively, without introducing a separate notation like $b_n$, you could directly prove the desired equation by strong induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see three consecutive terms of the series and suppose that n is even:

$a_n=2^n - 3^n-n-1$

$a_{n+1}=2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1}-(n+1)-1$

$a_{n+2}=2^{n+2} -3^{n+2}-(n+2)-1$

Form the sum of $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+2}$:

$a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}=(2+4)2^n+(3-9)3^n-2n-5=6\overbrace{{(2^n-3^n-n-1)}}^{a_n}+4n+1$

***$a_{n+2}=6a_n-a_{n+1}+4n+1$***

We can do this for odd n, the result is same.